# ¿Por qué mi condicional if no funciona correctamente?

Tags: c++, c

tengo un problema con mi codigo, se supone que con la condicional `if` si es mayor a `8` tiene que aparecer como "`aprobado`" y si es menor no me tiene que aparecer nada, pero no importa que numero ponga me sigue apareciendo"`aprobado`".
Como puedo arreglar esa cuestion???

```
#include "iostream"
#include "math.h"

//Dado como dato la calificacon de un alumno en un examen, escriba "aprobado" en caso de que esa calificacion sea mayor a 8.

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int CAL = 0;
    cout<< "CALIFICACION:";
    cin>> CAL;

    if ( CAL > 8);
    {
        cout<< "APROBADO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: typo: remueve el `;` en `if ( CAL > 8);`

Comment: Las librerías estándar deberían incluirse usando `<>`: `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba quitando el punto y coma despues del `if` no va:

Cambia esto:

```
if ( CAL > 8);
```

por esto:

```
if ( CAL > 8)
```

me cuentas como te fue... ReNiceCode...

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema era el ( ; ) en el if ( CAL > 8), gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De nada Bro siempre es un placer ayudar... X) ReNiceCode...

Comment: @JulioC. Bueno, y por dar la explicación, lo que ocurre si pones el `;` después del `if` es que entonces estás dando una "sentencia vacía" como lo que hay que ejecutar en caso de que la condición sea cierta. Lo que vaya después del `;` ya no forma parte del cuerpo del `if` y se ejecutará incondicionalmente.

Comment: @abulafia gracias por terminar de conextualizar... Saludo bro

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias por la información , me servirá de mucho.